# Coded a Discord and I think it doesn't see the rest of my code

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

I made a code, and here it is:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

            if message.content.startswith('G!Help'):
                await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention} Here are some commands you can use: Who, Yeet, Why, Help'.format(message))

                if message.content.startswith('G!Who'):
                    await message.channel.send('You are {0.author.mention} WOW!'.format(message))

                    if message.content.startswith('G!Yeet'):
                        await message.channel.send('{0.author.mention} Yeet!'.format(message))

                        if message.content.startswith('G!Why'):
                            await message.channel.send('Erm, {0.author.mention} Why What?'.format(message))


client = MyClient()
client.run('Insert token here')
```

Sorry for the formatting, that's how the site makes it, So, from

```
if message.content.startswith('G!Help'):
                await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention} Here are some commands you can use: Who, Yeet, Why, Help'.format(message)) to  if message.content.startswith('G!Why'):
                            await message.channel.send('Erm, {0.author.mention} Why What?'.format(message))
```

it doesn't work, any help? and the insert token here 
 thing has a token, just that I deleted it cause I don't wanna leak it, Help is very appreciated.

Comment: No, the formatting is not "how the site makes it". Please edit the question to show the real formatting, your question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: It looks like an indentation issue.  All of your `if` statements should be on the same level.  As is, your code only checks the second condition if the first condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
        if message.author.id == self.user.id:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message))

        elif message.content.startswith('G!Help'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention} Here are some commands you can use: Who, Yeet, Why, Help'.format(message))
```